# How to dispatch and wait for a variable number of actions?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I have an app which displays a table of stats about team members for all teams the current user is a member of.

- The team list api returns an array of team ids.
- The team member list api accepts a team id and returns an array of team member ids.
- The stats list api accepts a *list* of team member ids and returns an array of stats.

When the app starts up, I:

- dispatch an action to fetch the user's list of teams.
- when fetching the list of teams succeeds, I want to dispatch an action to fetch the list of team members for each team.
- when fetching the team members for each team succeeds, I want to dispatch the stats list action with all the team ids.

I'm not having any troubling dispatching a team member list action for each team id I receive, but I can't seem to 'wait for' all the team member list success actions to dispatch the stats actions.

Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
// actions
const TEAM_LIST = 'TEAM_LIST';
const TEAM_LIST_SUCCESS = 'TEAM_LIST_SUCCESS';
const TEAM_MEMBER_LIST = 'TEAM_MEMBER_LIST';
const TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS = 'TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS';
const STATS_LIST = 'STATS_LIST';
const STATS_LIST_SUCCESS = 'STATS_SUCCESS';

// action creators
const teamList = () => ({ type: TEAM_LIST });
const teamListSuccess = (teamIds) => ({ type: TEAM_LIST_SUCCESS, teamIds });
const teamMemberList = (teamId) => ({ type: TEAM_MEMBER_LIST, teamId });
const teamMemberListSuccess = (teamId, teamMemberIds) => ({ type: TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS, teamId, teamMemberIds });
const statsList = (teamMemberIds) => ({ type: STATS_LIST, teamMemberIds });
const statsListSuccess = (stats) => ({ type: STATS_LIST_SUCCESS, teamMemberIds, stats });

// epic
const fetchAllStats = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType(TEAM_LIST_SUCCESS)
    .switchMap((action) => {
      return concat(
        action.teamIds.map(teamMemberList),
        zip(action$.ofType(TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS)
          .take(action.teamIds.length)
        ).map(statsList)
      )
    });
};
```

I'm definitely using the zip/take combination wrong because I'm getting a STATS_LIST action for each TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS action emitted.

How can I modify this to dispatch the statsList action with the result of all team member list success actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `forkJoin` would fit your scenario well. You can pass it an array of inner observables (one for each of the `TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS` actions you want), it will emit only after they all complete, and you'll get an array of all the `TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS` actions it captures.

```js
const fetchAllStats = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(TEAM_LIST_SUCCESS),
  switchMap(action => merge(
    from(action.teamIds.map(teamMemberList)),
    forkJoin(...action.teamIds.map(teamId => action$.pipe(
      filter(action => action.type === TEAM_MEMBER_LIST_SUCCESS && action.teamId === teamId),
      first(),
    ))).pipe(
      mergeMap(actions => actions.map(action => action.teamMemberIds).map(statsList)),
    ),
  )),
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I modified this slightly so that the id lookups are taken from the store since there's a refresh action that can trigger the stats lookup again.